# I want to get dates from a table in access and check if it is todays date in Eclipse, but it is giving me errors

Tags: java, datetime

I want to be able to select the date from a column in access table and compare the date with todays date however I keep getting some sort of an error that tells me something is either wrong with my format or there is an internal error.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
DateTimeFormatter formmat1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

JButton btnLoadTable = new JButton("Load Table");
btnLoadTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        try {
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:\\testing.accdb");
            String sql="SELECT Description,Name,Due_Date FROM Homework  where Due_Date = '"+formmat1+"' ";
            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
btnLoadTable.setBounds(534, 96, 141, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnLoadTable);
```

Comment: I haven't used Java in ages, but to me it looks like you're only passing your `DateTimeFormatter` to the query and never even touch the `LocalDateTime` object that would actually contain the date you want.  Also, please post the error message you're receiving.

Comment: So I changed the query to "where due-date=ldt" and the error I get is
UCAExc:::4.0.4 incompatible data types in combination 
 This exception may  happen if you add integers representing units of time directly to datetime values using the arithmetic plus operator but without specifying the unit of date. 
   In this specific case you have to use, for example, <dateColumn> + 1 DAY.

Comment: You should read about prepared statements with parameters, for example [here: Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).